# Show form name = value pairs in console with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I've tried over a dozen solutions, none of them are just letting me do

`console.log(name + " " + value);`

without some kind of wonky JavaScript thing I'm not seeing how to do (I get like 90% of everything in different combinations)... I need to get inputs and selects and textareas, even preferably hiddens, everything you would type or click on a typical form (except for file upload).

Comment: I don't have much to add to the answers that already exist, but I will mention that you may want to use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class in your selector when selecting form elements to avoid selecting file upload elements if they exist in the form and you don't want them: `document.querySelectorAll('#form-name input[name]:not([type="file"])')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) constructor, passing in the `form` that you want the key-value pairs of. If you pass in the `form` as an argument, it will automatically contain the form's current key/value pairs (the key being the name of the elements and the value being their value). File input content will also be encoded, making it ideal for AJAX calls.

```js
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));
console.log(...formData);
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <div>
    <label for="username">Enter name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"value="John">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="useracc">Enter account number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="useracc" name="useracc" value="123456">
  </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

If you want all of the key/value pairs inside an Object, you could loop through all of the elements inside the form with a name attribute present to set the property of the Object equal to the name of the element to the value of the element.

```js
var formMap = {};
var formElems = document.querySelectorAll('#myForm [name]');
for(var i = 0; i < formElems.length; i++){
  var elem = formElems[i];
  formMap[elem.name] = elem.value;
}
console.log(formMap);
//now you can get the values of the form element with a particular name like so:
//formMap["username"];->"John"
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <div>
    <label for="username">Enter name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"value="John">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="useracc">Enter account number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="useracc" name="useracc" value="123456">
  </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution via `querySelectorAll` is possible. You could select all descendants of `form` elements that have `name` attributes, and then iterate the result, logging each element to console, like so:

```js
document.body
.querySelectorAll('form [name]')
.forEach(element => {

   console.log('name:', element.name, 'value:', element.value);
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="name" value="bob" />
  <input name="age" value="30" />
</form>
```